# Stylesheet linked but not loaded?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

rebuilding an app from rails 3.2 to 4, and all went well enough except some of my stylesheets are not being applied. When I ctru-U they seem linked ok:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Badge2</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Badge2">
    <link data-turbolinks-track="false" href="/assets/application.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link data-turbolinks-track="false" href="/assets/badges.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link data-turbolinks-track="false" href="/assets/framework_and_overrides.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link data-turbolinks-track="false" href="/assets/home.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link data-turbolinks-track="false" href="/assets/scaffolds.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/turbolinks.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/bootstrap-transition.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/bootstrap-affix.js?body=1"></script>
...
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/badges.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/home.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/application.js?body=1"></script>
    <meta content="authenticity_token" name="csrf-param" />
<meta content="0kPf5I9Ayz6yEM/RLbfyYmzTdixuoyf5Z4w9iPyuGaU=" name="csrf-token" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
```

But when I click on `/assets/badges.css?body=1` it is blank. (And of course its styles are not applied.) Scaffolds and framework load, but home and badges don't. (Or load blank/empty). What am I missing?

Comment: the initial "/" on the "src" property means that it is looking for the assets folder on the root of your webpage. Have you check if the root contains this folder "assets"?

Comment: Lc, application.css loads fine, but badges.css doesn't (They're in the same assets folder). I think badges.css is supposed to be shoved into application.css by the RAILS asset pipeline, but it doesn't seem to be.

Comment: I added this to the stylesheet: '/*
 * Badges.css
 */ ' and all is well. Except my sanity which is still thoroughly confused.

Answer (score 0):

The answer seems to be that this line:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

needed a trailing /.

I copied it from the old rails 3.2 app, where it worked.

Oddly, there were already css comments in the badges.css file, bus sass strips out single-line comments (//...) and preserves multi-line comments (/* ... */ ).